# Here in this exercise im trying to compute P(lim sup $A_n$) and P(lim inf $A_n$) where $A_n=\{n, n+1, n+2,...\} $which is a sequence of sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\omega=N$ and let $B$ be sigma algebra of subsets of $N$ so that $(N,B)$ is a measure space. Let $P$ be a function defined on $B$ ie $P: B\to[0,1]$ be a probability measure s.t for any singleton
$A=\{n\}$  $P(\{n\})=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.
Let $An=\{n,n+1,n+2...\}$
Compute $P($lim inf$ A_n)$ and $P($lim sup$ A_n)$
This is my attempt

[image]

Comment: (1) What have you tried? What are the definitions of $\lim \inf A_n$ and $\lim \sup A_n$? Then what are they here?

Comment: @Henry Yeah. My bad

Comment: I just insert my solution. Could you please check it. @Henry

Comment: $\lim \sup A_n$ and $\lim \inf A_n$ are both empty.

Comment: You have not correctly applied the definitions of $\lim \inf A_n$ or $\lim \sup A_n$. [Wikipedia might help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior).

Comment: I used borel cantelli theorem. To compute p(A1)....p(An) and the final sum is infinity so that p(lim sup An)=1.

Comment: @geetha290krm could you please insert your solution since I use the definition to compute it but I didn't get any thing

Comment: The second Borel-Cantelli theorem has the form "If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) = \infty$ AND the $A_n$ are independent, then $P(\limsup A_n) = 1$."  In your application, you have forgotten the second assumption, which is far from true.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ belongs to $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$ then $k \ge n$ for infinitely many $n$ which is impossible. Hence, no point belongs to $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$. This makes $\lim \inf A_n \subseteq \lim \sup A_n =\emptyset$ and empty set has probability $0$.